# Sharepoint: rich text editor suddenly throws javascript error

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

yesterday I installed Sharepoint Services 3.0, and the rich text editor was working without problems in IE9 on my laptop and on another laptop. But now, if for example I go to a content editor web part, and click edit / modify shared web part, and then on the 'Rich Text Editor' button, I get the error:

```
An error has occured in the script on this page.
Line: 1056
Char: 2
Error: Unable to get value of the property 'body': object is null or undefined
Code: 0
URL: http://address/_layouts/1033/form.js?rev=...
```

It's not working in any other browser on these laptops. If I go to yet another machine, here it still works in IE9, but I guess this will be broken too at some time!

Any idea what is going on here and how I can fix this on my laptop?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the reason, it seems that I used IE 64 bit which has limited support. Using the 32 bit version solved everything. See also http://ludwigstuyck.wordpress.com/2012/10/22/sharepoint-integration-with-ie-9.